# Existence of Principal Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

My first question is DOES a Principal Ideal always exist in a ring?
(My thoughts: By it's very definition any element can generate a PI and hence it exists)

Follow-up question: (If answer to 1st question is YES)
Please have a look at the alternate proof I have in mind for the following question:

Question: Prove that a commutative ring R with unity whose only ideals are <0> and R itself is a field.

PROOF: Let "a" be any element belonging to R. (Assume a to be non-zero)
Consider < a >.

Now since only ideals are <0> and R itself, and since a is non-trivial, < a > must be equal to R.

< a > contains elements of the form {r1a, r2a, ...} for all r belonging to R.
But since < a > = R, one of these elements MUST be UNITY!

Hence there exists ri such that r1a = 1.
Hence showing the existence of inverse of a.

Furthermore since a is ANY element belonging to R we have shown that for every element an inverse exists. Hence it's a field (other properties already satisfied)
(Left inverse proof is trivial from above)

What is the problem in this PROOF?

Comment: What makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: Because the solution given in the book and the professor is "supposedly" the shortest solution, but is longer than this. Hence the doubt.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. To answer the question in your first paragraph, yes, every element generates a principal ideal.

Comment: So I can think of Ideal to be analogous to cyclic group generated by an element like in group theory?

Comment: Better to think of $\langle a\rangle$ as $aR$.  This is the right principal ideal generated by $a$, but with a commutative ring it's just the principal ideal.  Then your proof becomes $1\in R=aR$, so $a$ has a right inverse.

Comment: My one quibble is that there may not be a nonzero element if $R$ happens to be the zero ring (in which case $0 = 1$). Most people don't consider the zero ring a field, so you probably want to assume $0 \neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This was already said in the comments, but I second it: the argument looks fine to me.

To address another point in the comments:

Yes, a prinicpal ideal is essentially the "rings" version of a cyclic subgroup. However, one subtlety worth noting is that for groups you have "cyclic **groups**" (not thought of as subgroups of some larger group). Cyclic groups basically look like cyclic subgroups, but in ring theory it's different: the analogous notion of a "cyclic ring" is quite different-looking from an ideal.

[ The group-theoretic analogy is stronger for related objects called "[modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics))" than for rings per se. In fact, this is no accident: abelian groups are precisely the same as modules over $\Bbb Z$. ]

Comment: This answer exists primarily to remove this question from the Unanswered queue. Please upvote or give it Best Answer to complete this process.